# Insert array to mysql database php

Tags: php, function, mysql, insert

I want to add an array to my db. I have set up a function that checks if a value in the db (ex. `health` and `money`) has changed. If the value is diffrent from the original I add the new value to the `$db` array. Like this `$db['money'] = $money_input + $money_db;`.

```
function modify_user_info($conn, $money_input, $health_input){
(...)
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {   
    while ($user = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $money_db = $user["money"];
        $health_db = $user["health"];
    }
    $result->close();

    //lag array til db med kolonnene som skal fylles ut som keys i array
    if ($user["money"] != $money_input){
        $db['money'] = $money_input + $money_db;
        //0 - 20
        if (!preg_match("/^[[0-9]{0,20}$/i", $db['money'])){
            echo "error"; 
            return false; 
        }

    }
    if ($user["health"] != $health_input){
        $db['health'] = $health_input + $health_db;
        //0 - 4
        if (!preg_match("/^[[0-9]{0,4}$/i", $db['health'])){
            echo "error"; 
            return false; 
        }   
        if (($db['health'] < 1) or ($db['health'] > 1000))
        {
            echo "error"; 
            return false;       
        }
    }
```

The keys in `$db` represent colums in my database. Now I want to make a function that takes the keys in the array `$db` and insert them in the db. Something like this ?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `main_log` ( `id` , ";
foreach(range(0, x) as $num) {

    $query .= array_key.", ";       
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -3); 
    $query .= " VALUES ('', "; 
    foreach(range(0, x) as $num) {

        $query .= array_value.", ";     
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -3); 
    $query .= ")";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `id` field is already set to be an Auto-Increment value, you do not need to declare it in the INSERT command (it is just assumed as not being over-ridden, and will fill with the auto-incremented value).

Assuming that `$db` is an an associative array, where the element keys are the same as the SQL field names, and the element values are the desired values for those SQL fields.

```
# Sanitise the Array
$db = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string' , $db )
# Create the SQL Query
$query = 'INSERT INTO `main_log` '.
         '( `'.implode( '` , `' , array_keys( $db ) ).'` ) '.
         'VALUES '.
         '( "'.implode( '" , "' , $db ).'" )';
```

That should produce an SQL query which will perform the required work. Plus it should reduce the possibility of SQL Injection attacks...

(Note: The line breaks, etc. above are for readibility only, and can be removed.)